# Office Interop reading incorrect cell values

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

Trying to iterate through the rows and cells on an excel spreadsheet, deleting empty ones. I'm using the following routine to do so.

```
foreach(Range row in sheet.UsedRange.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        Range cell = row.Cells[1, i + 1];
        if (cell.Value == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value.ToString()))
        {
            cell.Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Which works fine for the first two rows. However, it then seems to go haywire.

The third row is completely empty. Yet as it iterates through the columns, when this loop gets to column "I", it reads a value there. The value is what's actually in row 4, column "J".

After that, it just gets worse, missing whole rows and reading incorrect values from the rows it does find.

I am baffled by this. Is there something obvious that I have missed?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do exactly? If you want to check the row, first check the row and then delete all cells. (Still need to do `i--` then)

Comment: I'm just trying to remove empty cells from a spreadsheet. I suspect the key to this is in your answer, where you imply that when cells are deleted, the automatic choice of shift is "up". I need it to be "left". I see the delete method has a paramater, which will hopefully solve things.

Comment: @PatrickHofman yes, that's the key. I'll edit your answer to include it, and then accept it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are missing something very obvious. You are deleting cells. After that operation, your calculation of which cell to pick doesn't work any more.

If you delete a cell, all other cells will move up. That causes your `row.Cells[1, i + 1]` to be incorrect. If you for example delete one cell in row 2, the value of the cell in the same column in row 3 will never get checked, since it is in row 2 then.

The direction of shift on deletion may also be a factor - you can control it by passing a parameter to the Delete function.

Simply recheck the same column when you delete one:

```
foreach (Range row in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        Range cel = row.Cells[1, i + 1];
        if (cel.Value == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(cel.Value.ToString()))
        {
            // default shift is up
            cel.Delete();
            // to shift left use cel.Delete(XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftToLeft);
            i--; // this will do
        }
    }
}
```